# Post a WordPress post on post request

Tags: wordpress, post

How can I post a post on WordPress through a post request without using the UI?
If possible I would also like to have guidance on how I can implement this with ACF fields.

Comment: Have you checked the [REST API documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) yet? If not, that should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) or a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) to write your custom functionality.

You can handle [AJAX requests](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) with a specific *action*, and call [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to create posts.

Example to get you started:

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_post', 'create_post_ajax_handler' );

/**
 * Handle the create post ajax request
 */
function create_post_ajax_handler() {
  // Get the post title from the ajax request
  // You can get whatever you have passed here
  // Also, perform any validations you might want
  $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];

  // Create the post
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_title' => $post_title,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    // you could also specify the 'post_type', 'meta_input' etc
  ), true );

  // Error handling
  if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
    // Send error response
    wp_send_json_error( $post_id->get_error_message() );
  }

  // Send success response
  wp_send_json_success( $post_id );
}
```

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_script' );

/**
 * Enqueue the ajax script
 */
function enqueue_ajax_script() {
  // Enqueue your JavaScript file with 'jquery' as a dependency
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'ajax-script',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajax-script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
  );

  // Expose the url to admin-ajax.php as `ajax_object.ajaxurl`
  wp_localize_script(
    'ajax-script',
    'ajax_object',
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
  );
}
```

```js
// Set the url as `ajax_object.ajaxurl` which is the url to admin-ajax.php
$.ajax(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    // Your action should match the name of your 'wp_ajax_{action}' hook
    action: 'create_post',
    // Pass any data you want
    post_title: 'Example post title'
  }
})
  .done((response) => {
    // Do whatever you want with the response (in this example, this would be the post id)
    console.log(response);
  })
  .fail((error) => {
    // Handle the errors
    console.error(error);
  });
```

You might also want to look into [Nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/), which help protect against [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/common-vulnerabilities/#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I haven't tested this code, but I hope you get the idea.</sub>

---

**Edit:** Since you mentioned that you use Advanced Custom Fields:

```php
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
  'post_title'  => $post_title,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  // You can set ACF fields in the 'meta_input' array
  'meta_input'  => array(
    'acf_custom_field_name' => 'an example value'
  )
), true );
```

---

**Edit #2:** Please read more about AJAX in WordPress on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Replying to your comment:

> to which URL should I make the ajax request in order for it to trigger?

On the Codex, under **AJAX in Plugins > [Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side)**

> You might also use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to make the URL available to your script, and generate it using this expression: `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`

---

> how do I insert the action "wp_ajax_create_post" in my post request?

On the Codex, **AJAX in Plugins > [Ajax on the Administration Side](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side)**

> Notice how the 'action' key's value 'my_action', defined in our JavaScript above, matches the latter half of the action 'wp_ajax_my_action' in our AJAX handler below.

Comment: Okay, and to which URL should I make the ajax request in order for it to trigger? And how do I insert the action "wp_ajax_create_post" in my post request?

Comment: @kostberg You send the ajax request to `admin-ajax.php`, which in my example is retrieved using `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` and exposed to the frontend using [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). The action name is just the 'create_post' part (`wp_ajax_{action}` is the hook). You can read more about ajax requests in WordPress on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: @kostberg Edited my answer to provide you with references to the Codex.